# Float in Ruby on Rails Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, floating-point

I faced a big problem: I have an API method, that returns JSON.

One of fields has property float and I need it to be `5.0`. But when I convert it to JSON it becomes `5`.

Even if I make this thing  `render :json => 5.to_f`  it returns me integer anyway. 
What do I need to do to have `5.0` in JSON response?
Many Thanks

Comment: `render :json => 5.to_f.to_s`, `5.to_json => "5"` `5.to_f.to_json => "5.0"` ?

Comment: No, I need float type, not string

Comment: The only "safe" way to hand decimals from language A to language B is to use a String.

Comment: Try it in the browser console, `{ "something": 98.79999999999999 }` converted by Javascript to `{something: 98.79999999999998}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All numbers are floats in Javascript. Numbers are "double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values".
if you want to do then you should have to do like this
when we render json there is no floating points >0 that's why it is showing as integer you can convert it to string value to do this like

```
 render json: 5.to_f.to_s
```

only if integer value is in object field then it will show as float

Answer (score 4):

All numbers are floats in Javascript. Numbers are "double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values".

see [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value).

What it means, is that, `5.0` and `5` are the same in JS. There is no differentiation of int, float or double. 
As JSON (which stand for JavaScript Object Notation) generally end up as a JS object, `5` represents a float. Since JSON format is mostly used for data transfert/communication purpose, the decision to omit the the decimal part must be to save a few bytes in the string that is passed around.

In @z.shan's answer, the `5.0` is passed as a string `"5.0"`. 
Depending on what you want, **I would recommend to keep the `5` as a number in the JSON payload**.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use conversion like that :

```
integer = 5
render json: ('%.2f'%integer)
```